# on subscribe getting error You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, http, observable, angular8

am getting the above error when i try to make a simple http service on click of  a button
i tried lot of things but nothing works

```js
this.myService.findProject(requestBody, this.sortingParamObj).subscribe(response => {
      console.log('subscribe err');
    },
      errors => {
          this.showAlert(errors);
        }
       
      });
      
      
      
      myService
      findProject(requestBody, paramsData): Observable<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    Object.keys(paramsData).forEach(function (key) {
      params = params.set(key, paramsData[key]);
    });
    Object.keys(requestBody).forEach(function (key) {
      params = params.set(key, requestBody[key]);
    });
    let url = API_URL.PROJECT_SCREEN.PROJECT_SEARCH_SCREEN.FIND_PROJECT;
    return this.http.get(url, { params });
  };
```

it gives me the result but it also gives an error 
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
and then it logs in console of subscribe
can anyone tell what am i doing wrong?

```
      html
      <table>
        <thead>
          <thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let pd of project.data" (click)="navigateToProjectDetails('details')">
              <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{ pd.projectId }}</a>
              </td>
        <tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: It should be related to you bindings in the view. Share your components html code too.

Comment: i placed a debugger in the subscribe and what i observe is before executing the console.log, error is printed in the console tab.

Comment: In html am just looping the list and displaying the data

Comment: Because you load your data asyc. `project.data` becomes `undefined` initally. You can avoid that kind of errors with using `?` in your bindings like this : `<tr *ngFor="let pd of project?.data"`

Comment: thanks but its not working. I also tried by replacing the project?.data  to [], empty array but it still displays same error.

Comment: am totally getting same error for 3 times. First one is on load, the second and third are displayed once i hit the service .